# Azure API Management subscription event

Tags: azure-api-management

When a developer ask to subscribe to a particular API product in the Dev Portal, if I checked the 'need approval' option, a workflow is created and the subscription is waiting to be approved by the administrator.
I have a use case where I need to do additional tasks before the approval, in particular I need to create an App in the AD for OAuth2 and set the right permissions.

I'm looking for a way to trigger a Power Automate workflow when a subscription is requested, then use the content of the event to execute tasks and then ask a user to approve the requested subscription (thanks to a Power Automate approval).

Unfortunately, the only way to be informed that a product subscription was requested is to receive an email and unfortunately, the content of this email cannot be customized. The default email content is not really useful to detect what subscription is about and to find additional settings.
Any ideas to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a walkthrough which uses the Logic App to customize the subscription approval workflow. It might be helpful for your case as well. Check it out: https://github.com/adamhockemeyer/Azure-API-Management-Custom-Subscription-Approval